# Can't get my React UI to appear when running Docker container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, go

I have a React client and Go server app that I am trying to containerize. This is my first time using Docker so I'm having a hard time getting it to work. My Dockerfile looks like this which I got from [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploying-go-react-to-heroku-using-docker-9844bf075228) guide

```
# Build the Go API-
FROM golang:latest AS builder
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app/server
RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-w" -a -o /main .

# Build the React application
FROM node:alpine AS node_builder
COPY --from=builder /app/client ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Final stage build, this will be the container
# that we will deploy to production
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /main ./
COPY --from=node_builder /build ./web
RUN chmod +x ./main
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ./main
```

My server code take in the `PORT` environment variable to set which port to listen to so I used the following Docker run command:
`docker run -p 3000:8080 --env PORT=8080 test1`. However, when I go to *localhost:3000*, I get a **404 page not found** response instead of my React app. I've tried several different combinations of the run command but I can't seem to figure out how to get my UI to appear. Is this something to do with my Dockerfile or is my run command missing parameters? Or both?

Comment: Have you confirmed that requests are actually being served by your server? E.g., by adding log output and watching the docker log, etc.

Comment: Yup, I can go to one of the api end points and see it’s being handled

Comment: If you are getting a 404 Not Found error, and not something like "connection refused" or "empty response from server", then the Go application is working and the `docker run` command is right.  Can you edit the question to include enough application code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've just followed the guide and it worked for me, can you add screenshots of your directories (project, server, client)?